# OpenAPI spec for abstract classes

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger, openapi

I'm using `SpringBoot 3.1.3` `java17` and I have situation similar to follows.

I have a `CommonReadOnlyService` like this:

```
public class CommonReadOnlyService<T, ID, R extends JpaRepository<T, ID>> {

 @Autowired
 R repository;

 public T findById(ID id) {
    Optional<T> entity = repository.findById(id);
    if (!entity.isPresent()) 
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("Entity not founr %d", id));
    return entity.get();
 }

 public List<T> findAll() {
    List<T> entity = repository.findAll();
    return entity;
 }

}
```

Each other `@Service` extends the above one as follows:

```
@Service
public class UserService extends CommonRedOnlyService<User, Integer, UserRepository> {

}
```

I have also a `CommonReadOnlyResource` as follows:

```
public abstract class CommonReadOnlyResource<ID, S extends CommonService<?, ID, ?>> {

 @Autowired
 S service;

 @GetMapping("/{id}")
 public D findById(ID id) {
    return service.findById(id);
 }

 @GetMapping
 public List<D> findAll() {
    return service.findAll();
 }

}
```

And each other `@RestController` extends the above one.

Clearly the reasons of this is to avoid rewriting the `findById()` and the `findAll()` method for each Controller.

But this way how can I specify the OpenaAPI Swagger3 `@operation` and the `@ApiResponse` of the different `findById()` and `findAll()` resources?

There is a way?

---

Thanks a lot for your reply @zufar-sunagatov but my idea is a little bit different.

All services that `extends` `CommonReadOnlyService` will not redefine the `findById()` and the `findAll()` method..

I need some trick to put a generic definition right here:

```
public abstract class CommonReadOnlyResource<ID, S extends CommonService<?, ID, ?>> {

  @Autowired
  S service;
  
  @Override
  @Operation(summary = "Find a {?} by the id", description = "Get a {?} by specifying the id of the {?}.", tags = { "?" })
  @ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = {?}.class), mediaType = "application/json") }),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The user is not found.")
  })
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public D findById(ID id) {
    return service.findById(id);
  }

  @GetMapping
  public List<D> findAll() {
    return service.findAll();
  }

}
```

For example about the schema I've read somewhere something like this: `@Schema(anyOf = User.class, Car.class ecc..)` but I don't know if I can do the same thing for all others annotation.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using SpringBoot 3.1.3 java17 and I have situation similar to follows.
>
> I have a CommonReadOnlyService
>
> I have also a CommonReadOnlyResource
> And each other @RestController extends the above one.
>
> But this way how can I specify the OpenaAPI Swagger3 @operation and the @ApiResponse of the different findById() and findAll() resources?

Yes, you can use the `@OperationOverride` annotation, which allows you to override the `@Operation` annotation on a method in a superclass.

For example, you can override `findById()` method in your `UserService` class the next way:

```
@Service
public class UserService extends CommonReadOnlyService<User, Integer, UserRepository> {

    @Override
    @Operation(summary = "Find a user by the id", description = "Get a user by specifying the id of the user.", tags = { "users" })
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = { @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class), mediaType = "application/json") }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "The user is not found.")
    })
    public User findById(Integer id) {
        return super.findById(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this kind of configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig { 

  @Bean 
  public OpenApiCustomizer myOperationIdCustomizer() {
    return new CustomApiPaths();    
  }

  public class CustomApiPaths implements OpenApiCustomizer {
    

    @Override
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        Collection<PathItem> paths = openApi.getPaths().values();
        for (PathItem path : paths) {
            for (Operation operation : path.readOperations()) {
                String tag = operation.getTags().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow();
                String method = operation.getOperationId();
                if (method.startsWith("findAll")) {
                    operation.setSummary(String.format("Recupera tutti i/gli %s", tag.toLowerCase()));
                    Tag apiTag = openApi.getTags().stream().filter(t -> t.getName().equals(tag)).findAny().orElseThrow();
                    setResponses(operation, apiTag, tag);

                } else if (method.startsWith("findById")) {
                    operation.setSummary(String.format("Recupera %s in base al loro id", tag.toLowerCase()));
                    Tag apiTag = openApi.getTags().stream().filter(t -> t.getName().equals(tag)).findAny().orElseThrow();
                    setResponses(operation, apiTag, tag);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void setResponses(Operation operation, Tag tag, String mess) {
        ApiResponses responses = new ApiResponses();
        ApiResponse responseOK = new ApiResponse()
                .description(String.format("%s trovati", mess))
                .content(new Content().addMediaType("application/json", new MediaType().schema(new Schema().$ref(tag.getExtensions().get("x-ref").toString()))));
        ApiResponse responseKO = new ApiResponse()
                .description("Errore Interno del server")
                .content(new Content().addMediaType("application/json", new MediaType()));
        responses.addApiResponse("200", responseOK);
        responses.addApiResponse("500", responseKO);
        operation.setResponses(responses);
    }
    
  }
}
```

adding an `@Extension` on resources `@Tag`:

```
@Tag(name = "Discussion", description = "Operation on discussions", extensions = @Extension(properties = @ExtensionProperty(name = "ref", value = "DiscussionDTO")))
@RestController 
.....
```

To retrieve the correct Object in the schema.

I don't know if it is a best practice to do so and any help is highly appreciated but, in the meanwhile, hope helps.